# Creating a Java flipping Dominoes Game

Tags: java

I am creating a java dominoes game.

This is how a gameboard will look:

```
SEEEEEEE
DDDDEEEE
EEEDEEEE
EEEDEEEE
EEEDEEEE
EEECEEEE
```

Each letter is an object.
S is a switch, it is the only value that can be touched.
D is a Domino, its state is either down or up.
C is where the game is won if a Domino hits C.

Each Object has coordinates, and will be initialized with coordinates.
ex.) S is in (0,0),
     and S is initialized as Switch S = new Switch(0,0);

My Questions are:

1.) When S is pressed how would I go about checking each side, to see if there are 
    Dominoes? What if there are on multiple sides(N,S,E,W).

Once Dominoes are found next to the switch their state must change to Down, and then we must check for more dominoes next to the Dominoes with the Down state, until all connected dominoes are down.

2.) How can I efficiently create different levels containing different orders 
    of these objects.
    I will be using a dual array since level sizes are static, 8 x 6.

3.) In the future I would like to make a gameboard with images, rather than text.
    How can I go about doing this?
    I'm thing give objects of a certain type a picture property and then display the     pictures on the board. Each object will be the same size.

Thank you,

Fernando Diaz

Comment: can one falling domino causes all 8 surrounding dominoes to fall assuming it is surrounded?

Comment: Would be more realistic if you had a direction component too. So you would hit the switch in a certain direction and dominoes would fall based on the direction they were hit in.

Comment: StartClass0830, Yes 1 Domino can cause multiple Dominoes to fall but only Dominoes places North,South,East, or West of it. Dogbane, Good idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I would go about it this way:

Let `Hit Queue` be a list of dominos that have just now been hit (imagine them as being in the process of falling, just about to collide with other dominoes).

If Switch can be considered a Domino, add it to the Hit Queue then start the following domino-toppling algorithm.

If Switch cannot be considered a Domino, perform the Check in the middle of the algorithm first, then begin the algorithm.

#### Domino Toppling Algorithm

```
While (Domino C is not Down) AND (Hit Queue is not empty):
    Let New Hits be an empty queue of dominoes
    For each Domino in Hit Queue:
        mark Domino as Down
        Check each adjacent position (NSEW) for a domino:
            If one is found, add a reference to it to New Hits
    Replace Hit Queue with New Hits
    Update GUI (make Down dominoes red or something)

Let Victory be a Boolean equal to whether Domino C is Down
```

This essentially moves outward in waves, updating the GUI after every wave. It ends when C is hit or when there are no more dominoes for any existing domino to hit.

Comment: Great Algorithm. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now How could these objects be created efficiently? Using a for loop and instantiating them row by row, One-by-One? There will be multiple different combinations of dominoes.

Comment: That's a very different question with a much less simple answer. There are a lot of ways you could do it depending on the sort of results you want to achieve and there is probably more than one way to achieve some of those results. One way I can immediatley think of would be to have an algorithm which creates a single, branchless "worm" of dominoes from a point (for a certain distance and/or to a specific point) then use that how you want. You could create branches by picking existing dominoes and ordering a worm be created from there.